# Why did Chizkiyahu Hide the book of Refuos

Tags: books-generally, choleh-sick, tractate-brachot, mishpatim

...and he shall provide for healing" (Mishpatim 21:19) nitna reshus larofeh lerapos (Bava Kama 85a) - so why did Chizkiyahu Hamelech hide the Sefer Herefuos (Brachos 10b)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Rashi* in *Pesachim 56a* writes that *Sefer HaRefuos* was hidden because their hearts were not humbled over their illness but were, rather, healed immediately.

*Rambam* in *Peirush Hamishna* (Pesachim 4:10)  rejects this approach arguing that just as one may not hold back food from the hungry, so too one may not withhold healing from the ill.

Instead, *Rambam* writes that the book contained remedies that are forbidden to use like the usage of talismans and similar forbidden items.

See *Chazon Ish* in *HaEmunah veHabitachon* (5:5) for an in depth discussion of this dispute.

Answer (score 6):

As Rashi explains in ברכות on 10b and in פסחים on 56a:

> שגנז ספר רפואות לפי שלא  היה לבם נכנע על חולים אלא מתרפאין מיד

People would not take the illness as a stimulus to do Teshuva, rather they would immediately look up the cure - and lose the divinely-sent lesson of the illness.